# How to format numbers like x-y when writing them into csv file

Tags: c#, csv

I have a data structure like this:

```
Data
   Request Detailed Number (RequestNumber - Request Line Item Number)
   Request Explanation
   Price
   ...
```

**Example**

```
Request Number  Explanation  Price
          10-5  Lorem Ipsum  15$
```

After I open the file which I have written data in cvs file, 10-5 is shown like datetime.

How can I enable this column to be shown its pure nature 10-5?

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: "*10-5 is shown like datetime*" - How exactly are you writing your data to file?

Comment: Do you mean that it is shown like a datetime when you open it in Excel?

Comment: Are you opening the CSV in excel?

Comment: yes exactly, forexample 10-5 is shown Oct-5-2012 when open it with excel

Comment: I know how to format but  most of computer users dont know how to format column in excel so  I have to write it appropriately.

Comment: Do you include quotes around your values in the CSV file?

Comment: no I just write the row data to csv file. Should I add?

Comment: Yes, try that. Or don't use Excel to open your CSV file. (Check out [CSVed](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/)).

Comment: Just to clarify this isn't really a programming question, your problem is related to the tool your using to view the data i.e. Excel. If you open up your file using Notepad for example, you will see the data has exported correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export/write it with a preceding single quote (ASCII code 39). Excel will see it as string. But be warned: it is a feature of Excel. Any other program that opens the CSV will "see" the single quote as part of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Putting an '=' before the double quotes will accomplish what you want. It forces the data to be text.

eg. ="2008-10-03",="more text"

Comment: If I open it on excel I will see that 10-3  or "= 10-3"?